# How to mock pytest.fixture decorator?

Tags: python, pytest

I wanted to write unit tests for pytest fixtures present in conftest.py
How do I mock decorator pytest.fixture?

Conftest.py

```
import pytest 

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse="True")
def get_ip(dict_obj):
    """Assume some functionality"""
    return dict_obj.get('ip')


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def get_server(create_obj):
    """Assume some functionality"""
    pass
```

test_conftest.py

```
mock_fixture = patch('pytest.fixture', lambda x : x).start()
from tests.conftest import get_ip  


class TestConftestTests:

    def test_mgmt_ip(self):
        assert mgmt_ip({"ip": "10.192.174.15"}) == "10.192.174.15"

 E   TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'
```

When I tried to **mock pytest.fixture** at the starting of the test module before importing functions to be tested, I am getting error - 
 `E   TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'`

If I **remove the lambda function**, I am getting `E       AssertionError: assert <MagicMock name='fixture()()()' id='4443565456'> == '10.192.174.15'`

test_conftest.py

```
patch('pytest.fixture').start()
from tests.conftest import get_ip  


class TestConftestTests:

    def test_mgmt_ip(self):
        assert mgmt_ip({"ip": "10.192.174.15"}) == "10.192.174.15"

E       AssertionError: assert <MagicMock name='fixture()()()' id='4443565456'> == '10.192.174.15'
```

Could someone help me to resolve the error ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`@pytest.fixture(scope='session')` is going to call your `lambda x: x` with the kwarg `scope`. A mock covering both the no-args and some-args versions of `pytest.fixture` might be:

```
pytest_fixture = lambda x=None, **kw: x if callable(x) else fixture
```

But it should be noted `pytest.fixture` doesn't do any registration by itself. It only marks the function as a fixture, by setting the `_pytestfixturefunction` attribute on it; afterward, pytest collects the fixture.

I'm not sure you're barking up the right tree for whatever you might be trying to accomplish. If you want to change what value a fixture has in certain contexts, classes and subclasses can be used to override parent fixtures. If you're trying to see whether a fixture is used, creating a new class and overriding the fixture with your assertion can be useful.